# Android display different views depending on state

Tags: android, android-view

I have an activity with a listview which displays some data I fetch from online. Before I display the listview, I have a progress indicator in the middle. The activity starts off with the listview hidden and the progress indicator shown, and I hide one and show the other when necessary. They're in a framelayout on top of each other. Now I want to add the possibility of displaying a textview with an error message instead of the listview if necessary. Is there any cleaner way of doing this than hiding two views and showing the desired one every time I want to change it?

Comment: If you want to display an error message only consider using of Toast message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a decent solution. Instead of a ViewSwitcher as suggested, I found ViewFlipper which allows for more than one view. Also it lets you set animations for changing between the views

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

Switching between views is a bit messy though

`mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(mViewFlipper.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.myView)));`

Could maybe use hardcoded indices too if there aren't too many child views.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I define my XML that contains a `ListView` with a Progress Bar.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
                style="@style/Spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp" >
            </ProgressBar>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Loading...."
                android:textColor="#F1F1F1"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="#000000"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#f1f1f1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the `Activity` that is used to fetch and display data (in my case, the Facebook API), in an `AsyncTask`, I check if the returned length of the data in a `JSONArray` is **0**.

For example:

```
TextView txtEmptyData = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
if (JAFeeds.length() == 0)  {
    txtEmptyData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else {
    txtEmptyData.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // DO THE REST OF THE PROCESSING TO FETCH THE REMAINING DATA TO DISPLAY
}
```

Because of the way the XML is defined, if the `length() == 0`, then the `TextView` becomes visible and gets displayed instead of the `ListView`

Comment: Hmm I can see how this would work, but it feels a bit hackish. I'm only a newbie to android though so I wouldn't know haha. I found another solution which I'm posting up

Comment: @dvdy: Glad you found a solution. :-). And, this is not a hack ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewSwitcher. You would add some views there and show their in order, calling showNext()

Comment: That only seems to allow two child views

Answer (score 0):

You may call at any time AdapterView.setEmptyView(View v) on an AdapterView object to attach a view you would like to use as the empty view.

The snippet is as follows:

```
empty = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.empty1);
 list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
 list.setEmptyView(empty);
```

Make sure you keep the ListView and TextView inside the same parent.

For detailed description please refer [this](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/08/adapting-to-empty-views/)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but it does help me with another one of my problems, thanks!